# requests how to send a payload to login and confirm the post was successful

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Hello so I am trying to login with requests library to snapchat just to practice and I don't know if the payload or data is correct.

heres my code:

```
    try:
        headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Safari/537.36'}
        url = 'https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.snapchat.com%2Faccounts%2Fwelcome'
        payload = {'username':'myusername', 'password':'mypassword'}
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        print(r.text)
```

note: I have except and everything runs smooth i just don't know if my payload worked or how could i return if the login was successful. This is what happens when I run the script:

````
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Log In &bull; Snapchat</title><!-- Meta --><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="origin" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" /><script>const PAGE_LOAD_START_TIME_MS = Date.now();</script><!-- Styles --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/semantic.min.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/dropdown.min.css" /><!-- Force reload of css file --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/snapchat.css?t=0" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/accounts.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/auth.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/static/styles/revoke.css" /><!-- Scripts --><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/semantic.min.js"></script><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/dropdown.min.js"></script><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/gtm.js"></script><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/accounts.js"></script><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/pixel.js"></script><!-- Favicon --><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/accounts/static/images/favicon/favicon.png" type="image/png" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://snapnet-cdn.storage.googleapis.com/fonts/avenir-next/avenirnext.font.css" /><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?hl=en-us&render=explicit" async defer></script></head><body><!-- Pusher is Needed for Top Navigation Menu --><div class="pusher"><div id="login-root" data-xsrf="Jvw-azBPshXgY3Q_KRiPtQ"data-continue="https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/welcome" data-is-dev="false"data-web-client-id="dea1ed5e-209a-42e0-9c55-e5b465acd3c2"data-business-accounts-enabled="true"></div><script src="/accounts/static/scripts/main.en-us.js?v=41f9d4f7dd0ac6bd3489ff005a59a9f3f02032607240c0204f40d1d829eaf7ac"></script></div><!-- End Pusher --></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0```

Theres no api so I cant use json to see if it works thanks in advance
````

Comment: Try writing the `html` you got to a file and opening it in the browser to see what twitter returned. Also look at the `status_code` if you got a redirect to a different page.

Comment: I think their is a chance my payload is wrong how do i check the website to see that the input is 'username': 'password'

Answer (score 0):

When you try to login to `Snapchat` via `Firefox` or `Chrome` you can look at the requests that are sent in the `dev-tools`.

There is indeed a `POST` request to `https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/login` with `username` and `passwort` like in your payload. But that's not all. There is also a `xsrf_token` and a `g-recatcha-response`.

Sadly you won't be able to spoof the `g-recaptcha-response` with the tools that are available to us mere mortals. So `Snapchat` wont accept you login even if everything else is correct.

Comment: so its not possible with requests?

Comment: No, not as far as I know. Sorry to break it to you.

Comment: Hey, if this answer answered your question please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, so that other users that come here later know that it works. Have a nice day!

Comment: hi they ansewerd my question but @wuerfelfreak how did you find the required payload so i know for future requests to other sites

Comment: You can use the [network-monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) in e.g. Firefox and look at the individual requests. In the [request-details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details) you will find a bunch of information about the request, containing among others your username and password.